# Googletest no such file or directory

Tags: c++, include, googletest

I want to import my c++ code in the testing file i'm using for unittesting, but googletest can't find it. When i try to import on another file on same folder level it works.

BUILD: https://pastebin.com/UR048jg4
WORKSPACE: https://pastebin.com/cZ4KuN4t
I'm trying to import my file like this

```cpp
#include "myvector.h"
```

```
├── BUILD
├── hello_test.cc
├── main.cpp
├── myvector.cpp
├── myvector.h
└── WORKSPACE
```

EDIT:
I don't know why, but i can't answer to comments. Thanks a lot to everyone
the problem was that i wasn't including myvector.h in my srcs in the BUILD file

Comment: How are you compiling your tests?

Comment: The way you set your include directory will depend on how you are building.

Comment: I'm assuming both `.cc` and `.cpp` are both extensions for C++ source files.  Probably should be consistent about the source file extension you are using.

Comment: I'm on linux, so file extensions don't really matter. plus on the documentation they were using .cc files

Comment: How do you build this? Do you use `cmake` or `bazel` or `make` or .... ? Or maybe you are building this manually?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, i wasn't including myvector.h in my bazel BUILD file. This is the correct file

```
cc_test(
  name = "hello_test",
  size = "small",
  srcs = ["hello_test.cc", "myvector.h"],
  deps = ["@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main"],
)
```